# React.js calling a button click from a different button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to to make a function that calls a button click.  I know how to do this using `document.getElementById('takePic').click()` but I am not sure how to do this in React.

I am using an input element in order to access a devices camera, but unfortunately the input button that generates cannot be easily formatted.

```
<input className={classes.takePic} type="file" accept="image/*"></input>
```

So what I want to do is set this input element's display to none and then instantiate the button click through the click of another button.

```
<Button className={classes.addImage} onClick="">
```

I am using material-ui if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this way :

```
<input id="takePic" className={classes.takePic} type="file" accept="image/*" />

<Button className={classes.addImage} onClick={this.handleClick}>


 handleClick=()=>{
   document.getElementById('takePic').click();
}
```

read more here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

Comment: yes , it is HTML dom click() method , in javascript

Comment: Have to wait 15 minutes from the time of the post. But I will